# Verify that suspend function has not returned a value after simulating some time

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to validate that a suspend function does not return anything at all in a certain test.

Consider the following situation:

```kotlin
val completionSignal = Channel<Unit>(capacity = 1, onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_LATEST)

suspend fun waitForCompletionSignal(): String {
  completionSignal.receive()
  return "Completion signal received"
}
```

I want to test this code with 2 unit tests, one that validates it returns the string when I provide the CompletionSignal with a value (thats the easy one).
And one that validates that it does not return anything when i don't give it anything. This is the hard one, since how long should I wait? And can i be sure the test fails if my code changes and suddenly the string is returned?

I got the following approach but I am missing some pieces:

```
@Test
fun `waitForCompletionSignal when completionSignal is provided assert result`() = runTest {
  // Start waiting for result
  val result = async { waitForCompletionSignal() }
  // Provide completion signal
  completionSignal.trySend(Unit)

  // Await result and verify its correct
  assertThat(result.await() == "Completion signal received")
}

@Test
fun `waitForCompletionSignal when completionSignal is not provided assert no result`() = runTest {
  // Start waiting for result
  val result = async { waitForCompletionSignal() }

  // TODO?? some validation that succeeds if the test is just like this, but fails when i do the following:
  completionSignal.trySend(Unit)
  // A regular await would wait indefinately, and checking if the deferred result is completed does not work very well as well.
}
```

I hope the question is clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not return anything"? Function can't return just nothing (well, it can throw). Did you mean that it waits forever?

Comment: Yes I want to validate that it waits forever without waiting forever

Answer (score 0):

I made an extension function on the deferred type to be able to wait for a max amount of time and after that it will return null. In my particular situation a delay time of 0 (so no delay whatsoever) is enough, but I can imagine that in some situations its useful to delay for a minimum amount of time.

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
suspend inline fun <reified T> Deferred<T>.awaitOrNull(
    time: Long = 0,
    crossinline actBlock: () -> Unit = { }
): T? = coroutineScope {
    actBlock()

    val timeoutJob = async<T?> {
        delay(time)
        null
    }

    return@coroutineScope select<T?> {
        this@awaitOrNull.onAwait {
            timeoutJob.cancel()
            it
        }
        timeoutJob.onAwait {
            this@awaitOrNull.cancel()
            it
        }
    }
}
```

Using this method i can write the following tests that fail / succeed as expected:

```
// Succeeds
@Test
fun `waitForCompletionSignal when completionSignal is provided assert result`() = runTest {
  val result = async { 
    waitForCompletionSignal()
  }.awaitOrNull {
    completionSignal.trySend(Unit)
  }

  assertThat(result == "Completion signal received")
}

// Succeeds
@Test
fun `waitForCompletionSignal when completionSignal is not provided assert no result`() = runTest {
  val result = async { 
    waitForCompletionSignal()
  }.awaitOrNull()

  assertThat(result == null)
}

// Fails (to prove that it works)
@Test
fun `waitForCompletionSignal when completionSignal is not provided assert no result`() = runTest {
  val result = async { 
    waitForCompletionSignal()
  }.awaitOrNull {
    completionSignal.trySend(Unit) // This (obviously) causes the test to fail, as I wanted.
  }

  assertThat(result == null)
}
```